# load() not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am converting frames to div. I am using jQuery's `load()` for this but it is giving me an error which I am not able to solve. Below is the code which I am getting the error. Please help.

```js
$('#abc').load('https://www.google.co.in/');
```

```css
#abc {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="abc"></div>
```

[Codepen Code](http://codepen.io/krezzyfella/pen/KzxpVe)

Comment: Firstly your snippet doesn't do anything because you haven't included jQuery. Once you do that you'll find you cannot do what you require due to the Same Origin Policy blocking a request to a third party domain: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.google.co.in/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: You can't load Google with the `.load()` this is because the CORS (_Access-Control-Allow-Origin_) rules they have.

Comment: $("#abc").attr("src", "https://www.google.co.in/"); i think it will workwith iframe

Comment: How do i add jquery in snippet, i have added in codepen but no idea about snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load file of same domain.Cross domain loading is not possible.